# About viscosity solutions of elliptic equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, viscosity-solutions

i am recently starting my studies on solutions of  elliptic pde's of second order in the sense of  viscosity.  From this study some doubts result, they are:

1. What is the motivation to introduce a new type of solution for a pde, besides the classic sense and weak sense?
2. What are the limitations that are overcome in finding viscosity solutions that other methods cannot provide?
3. What to break from the classical theory of dust when looking for solutions via viscosity?
4. Is there any physical interpretation for a viscosity solution?

Comment: Did you look at the famous Crandall–Ishii–Lions paper? https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1992-27-01/S0273-0979-1992-00266-5/

Comment: Any good reference on viscosity solutions will answer all these questions in the introduction. What are you reading? As Hans pointed out, the standard reference is the Crandall-Ishii-Lions paper.

Comment: The first paragraph of the 1992 user guide article states "The theory encompasses classes of equations that have no solutions that are differentiable in the classical sense." This pretty much answers your 1. and 2.